# Necessary vs sufficient conditions - matrix definiteness

Tags: linear-algebra, logic, quadratic-forms, positive-definite

I'm having a little trouble understanding the wording of this theorem, and what it's implications are.

Theorem: If $A$ is an $n \times n$ symmetric matrix then for it to be positive definite it is:

- Sufficient: all leading principal minors be positive
- Necessary: all principal minors be positive

My understanding of sufficient vs necessary was that:
(S) is a stronger condition than (N) in that it's possible (N) can be satisfied but A isn't Positive definite, whereas as long as (S) is satisfied, A is always positive definite.

But in this case, doesn't (N) imply (S)? If all principal minors are positive, then all the leading principal minors are positive, and hence A is PD.

I'm confused by the meaning of necessary and sufficient here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are generally right:

- “(S) is a sufficient condition for (P)” means: $(S) \implies (P)$,
- “(N) is a necessary condition for (P)” means: $(P) \implies (N)$.

The reverse implications do not necessarily hold, but *may* hold: in that case we have a “necessary and sufficient condition” for (P), i.e. a condition which is equivalent to (P).

That is what happens in your case: From the circular implications 
$$
\begin{align}
 &\text{All leading principal minors are positive} \\
\implies &\text{$A$ is positive definite} \\
\implies &\text{All principal minors are positive} \\
 \implies &\text{All leading principal minors are positive} 
\end{align}
$$
it follows that both your conditions are equivalent to $A$ being positive definite, i.e. both are necessary *and* sufficient.